# How can I register 'regexp' function in spring data jpa?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I want to use the regexp function(in mysql) in spring data jpa.
I tried 3 ways that I searched on internet.

1. `findByUriRegex`, `findByUriMatches`, `findByUriRegexMatches`

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported keyword REGEX (1): [MatchesRegex, Matches, Regex]
```

This keywords are in [spring docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/2.0.0.M1/reference/html/#repository-query-keywords), but it doesn't work.

2. registerFunction

```yaml
spring:
  jpa:
    database-platform: com.xxx.config.DBCustomDialect
```

```kotlin
class DBCustomDialect : MariaDB53Dialect() {
    init {
        registerFunction(
            "REGEXP",
            SQLFunctionTemplate(
                StandardBasicTypes.BOOLEAN, "?1 REGEXP ?2"
            )
        )
    }
}

class EntityRepository: JpaRepository<Entity, Long> {
    @Query(value = "SELECT e FROM Entity e WHERE FUNCTION('REGEXP', e.uri, :regex)")
    fun findBy(regex: String): List<Entity>
}
```

But validation failed exception occurred.

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected AST node: function (REGEXP) near line 1, column 102
```

I don't know what I did wrong..
How can I solve it?

Answer (score 0):

I've found solution.
You need to validate `SQLFunctionTemplate`'s return type.

```
@Query(value = "SELECT e FROM Entity e WHERE FUNCTION('REGEXP', e.uri, :regex)
```

-> it doesn't work

```
@Query(value = "SELECT e FROM Entity e WHERE FUNCTION('REGEXP', e.uri, :regex = true)
```

-> it works